# Asp.net 2 website Authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication, iis-express

Server Error in '/' Application.
Login failed for user '****'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '********'.

Source Error:

```
Line 39:         catch (Exception ex)
Line 40:         {
Line 41:             throw ex;
Line 42:         }
Line 43:     }
```

Source File: d:\newigpbackup - Copy\App_Code\CS Code\Indus.cs    Line: 41

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '********'.]

```
Indus.ForumErrorLog(String Error, String ErrorPage, String IP) in d:\newigpbackup - Copy\App_Code\CS Code\Indus.cs:41
   MainHome.FillBottomBoxes() in D:\newigpbackup - Copy\MainHome.master.vb:246
   MainHome.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\newigpbackup - Copy\MainHome.master.vb:53
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8794; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8794

Comment: The error message tells you EXACTLY what the issue is.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '********'

Comment: Errors that start with 0x8 are invalid pointers.  So the results is returning a null.   So it looks like the connection string to the SQL Server is wrong.  The credentials are not correct.  Is the database using Windows Credentials or SQL Credentials?  Is the app failing on the PC that contains the Server or from a Remote PC?

Comment: Side note: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;`. Also, why catch an exception if your only action is going to be to throw it again? You might as well not have the try/catch at all if you're going to do that.

Comment: @jdweng connection strings are perfect. Opened the website on home pc after 4 months. sql uses mixed authentication. My VS identifies me as PC login mail id.sqlserver mgt studio has completely different user and password. but it worked always before I took break. Thanks

Comment: @jdweng If I use windows authentication while login through sqlserver mgt studio, it logs me in without any credentials. Property shows this user as public and access is limited and that too by sa.I am just beginning out.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean that it always worked before I took break?  I suspect you had a cookie or certificate that expired.You should be using the same server name in C# application as the login window to SSMS.Don't use the mdf filename in the connection string it will cause issue with login because the database owns the file which may be different that the user credentials.Instead specify the initial database.  The server know where the mdf file is located by the database name.  Window credentials in SQL Server uses a Group Account in Windows and you login should put you into the Group.

Comment: I mean i was working upon this until october lastly, after hat I just restarted yesterday. Reg cer/cookie ; how do I find out that ?

Comment: @seema start login to MS SQL Server Studio with the credentials that you are using in your connection string. Once you get in then you know the credentials are good. It definitely finds the server since it knows the user/pass is incorrect. but the error is clear.